# Certain GPO settings are not taking effect on Clients

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I've been trying to deploy a printer with Print Management on Server 2012 however it never appears on any of the clients after deployment.

And this is not only the case with printers, the same thing happens when I deploy Desktop Shortcuts to the clients.

Basically anything that changes the desktop, adds software, edits components etc does not work but things like disabling the Task Manager seem to work fine.

All clients login with their own DOMAIN\X accounts and GPRESULT /R shows me that the policy has been applied.

GPUpdate [/force] [/boot] runs succesfully.

-

Where can I start debugging this?

I've only been working with AD & DCs since a week ago and it's very unclear to me why this is not working properly.

Comment: Use gpresult /h to generate an HTML report of group policy application.  It will show any errors that occurred while processing the group policy preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Printers and desktop items are set by the USER policy, not by the MACHINE policy. So make sure that your policies are set to apply to the appropriate scope and have the appropriate permissions.

If you have a policy that is set to be processed by machines, but it only change user-specific items, it the policy will apply, but no changes will result.